# How to loop over array of hashes and remove a hash where a key has a specific value?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to loop over an array of hashes containing a set of keys and values, in this loop I want to check whether any key (or a set of specific keys, whatever that is most simple) has a certain value.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work as the hashes containing a key with the value *dollar* is still present within the array:

```
remove_currency = [{a: 'fruit', b: 'dollar'}, {a: 'fruit', b: 'yen'}]
currency = 'dollar'
remove_currency.delete_if { |_, v| v == currency }
```

Hope I made myself clear enough!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[mcve]". We need to see the minimal code, along with supporting input, that demonstrates the problem. Your code doesn't do that. Remember that SO isn't only about helping you, it's about helping others in the future, so we need your help asking questions that explain the problem fully.

Comment: Better? Still managed to get an answer that solved my problem, which means that someone understood my question anyway. And I do believe that users, what experience they might have, can imagine that my `remove_currency` array contains a bunch of hashes and some of them including the value of `'dollar'` and some of them not. So I can't see the point of this frankly ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
things = [{foo: 3, bar: 42}, {baz: 5, quiz: 3.14}]
things.reject { |thing| thing.values.include? 42 }
  # => [{:baz=>5, :quiz=>3.14}]
```

Comment: ✅, you've been AWOL.